# Rails 3 Server Wont Start On Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created my first test app using ruby 2 and rails 3. When I use the command `rails server` I get this:

```
/Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/speedy/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/speedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
Speedys-MacBook-Pro:simple_cms speedy$
```

Not sure what seems wrong. Any pointers?

Comment: You're missing the MySQL native library.

Comment: Did you install mysql with brew? If yes, did you load mysql?

Comment: OP just needs to make sure the mysql client library is installed.

Comment: Hi all. I have installed mysql via a .dmg file. I have found the answer: In the database.yml file, I need to set the correct database and password. Now I have a loaded WEBrick :)